# Thymeleaf doesn't render variables within messages in some locales

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, locale

I have a text for a key in my `messages.properties` file with variables in it:

```
some.key=You'll need to pay {0} {1} in order to continue.
```

and I have it in both locales that my application supports: `messages.properties` for English, and `messages_tr.properties` for Turkish (the default `Locale`).

So this works when I render the page with Turkish locale:

and I get:

```
Some Turkish words 10 USD some other Turkish words.
```

So, `{0} {1}` gets replaced with the amount and currency. But it doesn't when I render the page in English:

```
You'll need to pay {0} {1} in order to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the single quote.

From [here](https://www.mscharhag.com/java/resource-bundle-single-quote-escaping):

> The single quote is used to represent a section within the message pattern that will not be formatted. A single quote itself must be escaped by using two single quotes ('')

So your message in messages.properties should be:

`You''ll need to pay {0} {1} in order to continue.`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what was happening.