# Spring MessageSource not using parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
    System.out.println(ex.errorArgument[0]);
    String defaultErrorMessage = messages.getMessage(ex.errorMessage, ex.errorArgument, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String localErrorMessage = messages.getMessage(ex.errorMessage, ex.errorArgument, defaultErrorMessage, locale);
    Logger.error(this.getClass(), "handleApiException()", ex.status+": "+ex.errorCode+": "+defaultErrorMessage+": "
            +(ex.chainedException==null?"No further exception.":ex.chainedException.getMessage()));
```

With the following message

```
api.censored=Name cannot have the censored word '{0}' in it. Please choose another.
```

However, it is not replacing the parameters!

```
2019-05-20 23:02:46.484 ERROR 10884 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.example.apis.RestExceptionHandler   : handleApiException(): 406: CENSORED_WORD: Name cannot have the censored word {0} in it. Please choose another.: No further exception.
```

The JavaDocs says

> String org.springframework.context.MessageSource.getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale)
>
> Try to resolve the message. Return default message if no message was found.
>
> - Parameters:
>
>   - code the code to lookup up, such as 'calculator.noRateSet'. Users of this class are encouraged to base message names on the relevant fully qualified class name, thus avoiding conflict and ensuring maximum clarity.
>   - args an array of arguments that will be filled in for params within the message (**params look like "{0}", "{1,date}", "{2,time}" within a message**), or null if none.
>   - defaultMessage a default message to return if the lookup fails
>   - locale the locale in which to do the lookup

Spring 4.3.24

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675147/thymeleaf-doesnt-render-variables-within-messages-in-some-locales/51677941#51677941)

Comment: Hmm, that was it! Thanks!